# DRAQ5 and PI incompatible?

Tags: nucleic-acids, staining, cell-cycle, flow-cytometry

I'm interested to analyse hemolymph cells from a marine mollusc. I wanna count only "alive" cells so my strategy was the following: DRAQ5+ (nucleated cells) and PI- (alive cells) and identify population in FSC vs SSC.

Staining independently with DRAQ5 and PI I found positive and negative populations for each one but, in the fully staining I lost DRAQ5+/PI+ population... (https://ibb.co/VpgcCTN)

Does anyone know if DRAQ5 and PI are incompatible?

Note:

- DRAQ5: excitation with 640nm and emission filter 675/25.
- PI: excitation with 488nm and emission filter 585/40

Comment: [Rieger *et al*. 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20381494) seems to be relevant. -- "Gating on the population of PI+/DRAQ5+ cells, we used the similarity feature to determine the degree of similarity between PI and DRAQ5 stains in goldfish primary kidney macrophages (Fig. 3A). We found that there was a sizable proportion of falsely stained PI positive in these cells, as well as in all unfixed primary cells and cell lines tested (Fig. 3B)."

Comment: For my proposal, I prefer to have more false-positive than false-negative cases. The problem here is that I don't have double staining as you can see [here](https://ibb.co/VpgcCTN). Independently, I have DRAQ5+ and DRAQ5- populations, the same happens with PI, I saw PI+ and PI- populations. But, adding both stains together I lost DRAQ5+/PI+ population...